# Is there a way to source a shell script in the makefile SHELL declaration?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Suppose I write:

```
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash

commands:
  source sourceme.sh && alias
```

But I wanted to push that `source sourceme.sh` back into the `SHELL` declaration:

```
SHELL:=/usr/bin/env bash -c "source sourceme.sh" # or something along these lines
```

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I use make as an integration system, just fine-tuning my style and approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.  Make takes your recipe lines and sends them to, effectively, `$(SHELL) -c <recipeline>`  The shell, unfortunately, doesn't accept multiple `-c` options so to do what you want you'd need to have a way for make to insert that string at the beginning of every recipe line and there's no way to do that.

You can do it yourself, from outside your makefile, by writing your own wrapper:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shift
source sourceme.sh
eval "$@"

$ cat Makefile
SHELL := wrapper.sh

commands:
        alias
```